# В какой момент лучше выполнять проверку в DDD

Tags: архитектура, проверка, ddd, модель-данных

Подскажите пожалуйста в какой момент лучше в выполнять проверку:

Представим себе стандартную ситуацию, допустим у нас есть какая то упаковка, в нее необходимо добавить какие то элементы, и сохранить. Но это действие сопряжено с некоторыми особенностями предметной области, по условию мы не можем добавит в упаковку элементы, которые не прошли предыдущую стадию, например они не окрашены.

Так вот, мы собираем данные с уровня представления, передаем их уровню сервиса прикладного уровня из которого начинаем вызывать модели предметной области. Пусть будет так, что мы хотим создать новую упаковку. Из репозитория получаем экземпляр этой упаковки с нулевм id (т.к. его еще нет в БД) и хотим добавить в список элементов этой упаковки наши элементы пришедшие с уровня представления. Вот тут-то и основной вопрос, должны ли мы разрешать добавлять в упаковку элементы и проверять всю валидность в момент сохранения или мы должны заблокировать добавление элементов в упаковку на самом этапе добавления их в коллекцию? Не судите строго, считаю это важным вопросом, потому как условие добавления - это по сути часть логики предметной области, т.е. по большому счету упаковка(или сервис доменного уровня) должна иметь метод по добавлению элементов с соответствующей проверкой. Так же хотел узнать, не будет ли это избыточным моментом?

Изменено:

считаю, что проверка должна быть в предметной области, чтобы логика не перетекала в слой сервисов прикладного уровня.

Но как быть, если сохранение этой упаковки затронет еще какие-то сущности, например элементы, которые были на складе окрашенной продукции должны быть перемещены в упаковку. Получается что нужно перенести часть логики, но уже на инфраструктурный уровень? Но этого бы очень не хотелось делать.

p.s. немного не в тему, но еще маленький вопрос, есть ли способ сделать так, чтобы какой-то сторонний класс например репозиторий, имел возможность создавать экземпляры другого класса, если у этого класса закрытый конструктор, короче суть в том, что я хочу сделать так, чтобы агрегаты создавались только из репозиториев.

Comment: " проверять всю валидность в момент сохранения или мы должны заблокировать добавление элементов в упаковку на самом этапе добавления их в коллекцию?" - а это не одно и то же?)) При провале проверке валидности вы же не сможете добавить элемент, а выбросите исключение. Разве нет?) Но в целом имхо нужно проверить, если мы можем добавить - то добавить/сохранить. Иначе - exception

Comment: спасибо за комментарий, но я считаю это не одним и тем же, потому что логика из предметной области будет перетекать в сторону сервисов прикладного уровня, хотя по задаче она явно принадлежит к доменному слою.

Comment: Возможно я неправильно применил термин валидация, я конечно же имел ввиду проверку на возможность добавления в упаковку элементов исходя из их готовности на более ранних этапах.

Comment: я думаю, в домене, т.к. ваш бизнес не может обрабатывать упаковку, которая состоит из не правильных элементов, поэтому и не должно быть способа создать "неправильную" упаковку, тогда это становится не валидацией, а pre-conditions/invariants

Comment: а если валидировать при сохранении, то часть логики "утекает" в application layer, что приводит к неочевидному поведению, если этот слой поменяется или если бизнес модель будет меняться, то про эти правила могут забывать/не учитывать

Comment: да мне тоже так кажется, но при сохранении же происходят и другие действия например эти элементы списываются со склада окраски. Или они должны тоже списываться в момент добавления в упаковку, а при сохранении происходит лишь запись в БД всех измененных данных? но как тогда отслеживать эти  данные мы же работаем с доменными сущностями, а не коллекцией из EntityFramework?

Comment: даже немного не так, агрегаты не хранят другие агрегаты напрямую, в следствии чего при сохранении сохранится сам агрегат и вложенные в него сущности, а связанные сущности по id по идее должны быть заново пересохранены с выполнением некоторых сценариев, но это опять же переносит часть логики только уже на инфраструктурный слой.